# Rows into Column

Tags: postgresql, pivot

> [image: this is my view]

I want to make the above view `vConsolPrchOrd` like below:

> [image]

Database: PostgreSQL 9.2

I want to create a Crystal Report with this view (I asked about this [on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23268166/how-to-make-a-crystal-report-with-following-view)).

Comment: Generally, we *very much* prefer text over images for data. One cannot copy / paste from images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You found [the reference to the basic `crosstab()` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905) in [your own answer to the duplicate question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23289530/939860).

Here is your solution, somewhat simplified, and cleaned up:

```
SELECT *
FROM   crosstab(
   'SELECT product, branch, orderqty
    FROM   vconsolprchord
    ORDER  BY 1'
 , 'VALUES(1),(3),(4),(5),(6)'   -- int is default type, matches "branch"
   ) AS tbl (product  varchar
           , branch_1 numeric    -- must match the type of "orderqty"
           , branch_3 numeric
           , branch_4 numeric
           , branch_5 numeric
           , branch_6 numeric)
LIMIT  5;
```

Answer (score 2):

assuming you have a **limited and known number of branches**, it could probably look like this:

```
select product,branch,
-- branch 1
       case when branch=1 then sum(orderqty) else null end as orderqty1,
       case when branch=1 then sum(prevmthsale) else null end as prevmthsale1,
       case when branch=1 then sum(curntstk) else null end as curntstk1,
-- branch 2
       case when branch=2 then sum(orderqty) else null end as orderqty2,
       case when branch=2 then sum(prevmthsale) else null end as prevmthsale2,
       case when branch=2 then sum(curntstk) else null end as curntstk2,
-- branch 3
       case when branch=3 then sum(orderqty) else null end as orderqty3,
       case when branch=3 then sum(prevmthsale) else null end as prevmthsale3,
       case when branch=3 then sum(curntstk) else null end as curntstk3,
...
from vConsoPrchOrd
group by product, branch
```

Notice this design has a poor maintanability (you will have to change your sql if a new branch is created), but it might suit your needs.

There might be a better solution using sql-2003, but I'm not an expert in these matters.

Comment: just see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23268166/how-to-make-a-crystal-report-with-following-view/23289530#23289530) ,i myself found a solution for this since i have no reputation to answer my own question here